# Compare two tables and update one table in Oracle-sql

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have two tables in oracle database 'test_DB' as tmp_book and author as follows

[image]

tmp_book table has a smaller set.
I need to compare these 2 tables as follows:
get the first 'book_id' in *tmp_book* table and in *author* search for that 'book_id' and update column 'is_available_image_url' with value 'Y'.

This way I need to do this for all the records in the *tmp_book* table

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

This is an `update` with some filtering:

```
update author
    set is_available_image = 'Y'
    where exists (select 1 from tmp_book b where b.book_id = author.book_id);
```